# Json comes out empty

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to serialize a json object to be stored in a database

The problem is the Json comes out empty as just `{}`

My code is

```
public Task ParseJson(){
   QuoteDataObject data = new QuoteDataObject();
   data.Source = "joe";
   var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
}
```

And the QuoteDataObject is

```
public class QuoteDataObject
{
    public string Source { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't come out emtpy - comes out as {"Source":"joe"} using your example. Can you advise how are you checking?

Comment: Not able to reproduce. Are you using Json.NET library?

Comment: *Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking*

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius I checked by looking in my Database also tried using DisplayAlert("test", json.ToString(), "test");

Comment: @Steve Yes, I am using Json.NET

Comment: The method that this is used in is async, does that affect it at all?

Comment: @Daniel you gave us a piece of code which works, but you are asking why it doesn't work. How do you expect this issue to be reproduced? It is very likely that the issue is somewhere else.

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius Actually, the issue was I used "SerializeObject" not knowing there was a "SerializeObjectAsync" that was needed for async methods, but no one else seemed to catch that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was I used `SerializeObject()` not knowing they had a `SerializeObjectAsync()` method that was needed for async methods.